# MVC ActionLink 'Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Hi I have a MVC View and I was wanting to make a ActionLink.

In my view I have:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Invoices) {
        <tr>
        <td>
        @Html.ActionLink(modelItem => item.Organisation.Name, "EditInvoice(" + item.Id + ")", "InvoiceController")
        </td>
        <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceDate)
        </td>
        <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalExcludingGst)
        </td>
        </tr>
    }
        </table>
```

The ActionLink method first parameter is causing some problems. I want to set the text to the Organisation Name. However it is throwing the error 'Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type'. The name property is already a string so I'm not sure what the reference is about.

Anybody know a way round this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass the linkText argument as a string.

I think you will also need to correct the actionName and controllerName arguments and pass the ID in the routeValue argument. Something like:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Organisation.Name, "Edit", "Invoice", new { Id = item.Id }, null)
```

Comment: @AnonyMouse I've updated my answer - I think you will need to fix more than just the linkText argument

Comment: Yeah, found those problems when I ran it. Thanks heaps for your help.